# I got a port scan (blocked by kaspersky antivirus on my windows 10 machine)

Tags: security, networking, port-scanning

I got a notification from my kaspersky antivirus on my windows 10 (which is always on)
Apparently, there was a port scan and it was blocked.

```
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
User type: System user
Component: Network Attack Blocker
Result description: Blocked
Name: Scan.Generic.PortScan.TCP
Object: TCP from 104.152.52.xxx at 192.168.0.10:1701
Additional: 192.168.0.10
Databases release date: Yesterday, 1/19/2022 12:34:00 PM
```

1. 192.168.0.10 is a virtual machine running debian; I have UFW on this debian and port 1701 is not in any UFW rules. (so it's not allowed)
2. I have done a grep on the ports of the debian VM using: `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 1701` Found nothing
3. I assume the port scan has been done on all the machines in my network?
4. How can I find out where the scan comes from?
5. What are the consequences? What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what i understand of what you published, `104.152.52.xxx` made a scan. What's odd is how could he effectively reach your machine at `192.168.0.10`, so i believe you have port forwarding enabled on your router. *-{see edit}

I also assume that the IP address of your VM is bind directly to your home network `192.168.0.0\24` (and not in a sub network on Windows 10). So your router should be accessible at `192.168.0.1` (or `192.168.0.254` sometimes)

**Consequences of a scan ?**

- most likely, none, except if you have some port opens, kaspersky blocked the 1701, but probably other ports have been scanned. So verify the configuration of your router

**Is it normal ?**

- Yes. Every device accessible from internet is constantly scanned. Always.

**What to do next ?**

- Make sure no port-forwarding is enabled on your router
- If port forwarding is enable, and needed. Make sure the software behind it is secured and up to date. if you have a password access, the password should be strong. If you have an SSH server, deactivate the authentication by password and activate the authentication by public key.

**== EDIT ==**

Other possibility than port forwarding and seems to be the answer:
If the VM is in a DMZ, then all unassigned ports on the router may be (depends on the router) redirected to the VM, therefore, a scan on the public ip address, would result on a scan on the VM.

Comment: "So from what i understand of what you published, 104.152.52.127 made a scan. What's odd is how could he effectively reach your machine at 192.168.0.10, so i believe you have port forwarding enabled on your router." that's what I find weird too and trying to find out why.

My debian VM is configured with bridge mode networking.

I have only one port forwarded on my router and it is not port 1701. Still don't understand how can 104.152.52.127 scan port 1701 if is not opened....

Comment: @yeahman 
It's not because a port is closed that it cannot be scanned. A scan is actually : sending packet to a port to know if it is open or closed.
So check : 
- Do you have a DMZ, if your VM is in a DMZ, then it can be scanned somehow.
- What is your public IP address (don't publish it here, search for "my ip" on google)
if you're IP is the one mentioned, somehow you're router is doing the scan.

Comment: I thought that if a port is not opened on the router, then a packet shouldn't arrive on one of my computer or VM?
I have DMZ on my router and my VM's local IP is in DMZ
"if you're IP is the one mentioned" => mentioned where?

Comment: Correction : if your ip is "104.152.52.xxx".  -- The packet still comes to your VM, and the OS discards it because the port is closed (see it as someone trying to open a closed door). But It seems that because it's bridged, your antivirus on the host system saw it coming and blocked it. -- I think it depends on the routers, but if your VM is in the DMZ then all unassigned port on the router may be redirected to it, so that would be the problem. Should I update the main answer and you mark it as resolved ?

Comment: 104.152.52.127 or 104.152.52.xxx is not my IP 
Can you elaborate what the DMZ exactly do? Maybe I have not understand its purpose.
I think I actually need to remove my VM from the DMZ right?

Comment: So, on some home router, if a device is in the DMZ, then ALL ports which are not assigned to something on the router (port forwarding, etc.) will be redirected to the device in the DMZ. But this is not on all router, you can see it written in the description of the settings of your router. But that would explain why a scan on the router, is actually scanning the VM.     
    
// [ I typed 104.152.52.xxx because it is bad practice to publish IP addresses online. I just hid the last byte - and you should do the same]

Comment: thx very much for the explanation. yes my router has this text in DMZ section: 
"It is a buffer between a secure system and an insecure system. If the WAN port is not listed in the port mapping table, the application requests from the WAN connection are forwarded to the DMZ device."

So I removed my VM IP from DMZ. I have nothing on DMZ now... what happen now if someone scans my WAN IP on a port not assigned on something on my router?

Comment: Then it will scan the router directly and all ports are closed by default, except the ports which are in the port-forwarding list (things that I advise you to use really carefully, as it's an open door to your network, the software could easily be vulnerable if not updated or with insecure password), or if you activated remote management of your router (which you shouldn't do in most cases) or other services activated (like VPN access)